# How to disable setOnMouseClicked while scrolling in JavaFX ListView

Tags: java, javafx-8, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I developed a small Javafx application and deployed in my Android device, I have a `ListView` which is configured something like this:

```
stuboutList.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        Dialog.show("You click the ListView!");
    }
});
```

**Here's the problem:** Every time I scroll the `ListView` the **Dialog** will keep on popping.

**QUESTION:** How to disable **setOnMouseClicked** while **SCROLLING?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scroll a `ListView` the swipe gesture triggers a Mouse Drag Event. You can set a flag, when the drag event is detected, and consume the following Mouse Clicked Event.

```
public class ScrollListener {

    private BooleanProperty scrolling;

    public ScrollListener(Node observableNode) {
        scrolling = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(false);

        observableNode.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.DRAG_DETECTED, e -> scrolling.set(true));

        observableNode.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, evt -> {
            if (scrolling.get()) {
                scrolling.set(false);
                evt.consume();
            }
        });

        observableNode.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, e -> scrolling.set(false));
    }

    public ReadOnlyBooleanProperty scrollingProperty() {
        return scrolling;
    }

    public boolean isScrolling() {
        return scrolling.get();
    }
}
```

Another possiblity is to you use Gluon's `CharmListView`, which takes care of the Mouse Click Event on its own, but (until now) is not as conveniend to use as the standard `ListView`, e.g. when you need to access the `SelectionModel`, as you can see in this question: [CharmListView SelectedItemProperty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054677/charmlistview-selecteditemproperty)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, how can I integrate your code to my code above?  ;)

Comment: You could call it in the `initialize()` method of the view controller: `new ScrollListener(listView);`. Also keep in mind that you have to remove the eventHandlers / filter if you need to be concerned about resources.